# Create a PDF file and download in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

In download profile method I am trying to create a method which downloads a pdf file when this method is called. I am not able to figureout where I am going wrong but I am not able to download the pdf. Please help me find the issue.

File.open doesnt download the file.

users_controller.rb

```
def download_profile
  @user=current_user
  file = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render_to_string(template: 'user/profile.pdf.erb', locals: { user: @user }))
  tempfile = Tempfile.new(["Profile", ".pdf"], Rails.root.join("tmp"))
  tempfile.binmode
  tempfile.write file
  File.open(tempfile.path, 'r')
  tempfile.close
end
```

profile.pdf.erb

```
<b>User Details</b><br /><br />
<%= user.name %><br />
<%= user.first_name %><br />
<%= user.address %><br />
```

user.vue

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mb-12">
    <v-form :model='user'>
     <a href="#" @click.prevent='downloadProfile(user)'>
       <span>Download</span>
     </a>
    </v-form>
   </div>
  </v-card>
</template>


<script>

  export default {
    data: function () {
     return {
      user: {
        id: '',
        name: ''
      }
     }
    }
    methods: {
        downloadProfile(user) {
          this.$axios.get('/users/download_profile.json')
        },
     }
  }
</script>
```

Update

```
def download_profile
  @user=current_user
  file = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render_to_string(template: 'user/profile.pdf.erb', locals: { user: @user }))
  send_data(file, filename: "file_name.pdf", type: 'application/pdf')
end
```

Comment: I think you should add vue and javascript tag too

Comment: @buncis sorry I didnt get you.

Comment: did you use rails api or rails normal?

Comment: @buncis normal rails

Comment: any suspicious rails log? when you call the url?

Comment: @user12763413 have you solved this issue?

Comment: Great! Maybe you can post it as an answer or edit the original post and maybe you will help someone in the future...

Answer (score 0):

have you check the url though? opening it in chrome url, did it downloaded just fine?

if yes then the problem is in your javascript code

try to use window.open instead axios get

I just tried creating a new rails app and just installing `wicked_pdf` and `wkhtmltopdf-binary`

and it just work fine

my controller code is like this

```
  def download_pdf
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string(template: "users/show"))
    send_data pdf, filename: 'file.pdf'
  end
```

Comment: the URL doesnt download the file. I dont think problem is with javascript. 
File.open doesnt download the file.

Comment: Please check the update portion in the question, on clicking the download button the file is not downloaded but if I open the URL(http://localhost:3000/users/download_profile.json
) then the file downloads.

Comment: if you could download with the url execution, then the problem is in your download button, check the url and the code, thus why I suggest to change your `axios get` to `window.open` instead, as per my original answer

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating the file, to download it, add:

```
send_data(file, filename: "file_name.pdf", type: 'application/pdf')
```

You can wrap it with 'respond_to':

```
def download_profile
  @user=current_user
  file = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render_to_string(template: 'user/profile.pdf.erb', locals: { user: @user }))
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf { 
      send_data(file, filename: "file_name.pdf", type: 'application/pdf') 
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Please check the update portion in the question, on clicking the download button the file is not downloaded but if I open the URL(http://localhost:3000/users/download_profile.json
) then the file downloads.